# Is There Any Risk When Visiting Websites Without Secure Connections If You Don't Enter Personal Info?

Tags: encryption, internet, websites

Sometimes when I click on a link to a website, from google search, etc., I get a warning that says "Your connection is not private. Attackers may be trying to steal your personal info", and makes me go into advanced options if I want to proceed to the website. According to some quick research, this means that there is an issue with the site's HTTPS encryption. My question is whether it is safe to visit these websites as long as you aren't entering credit card info or other personal info, or whether there is some other risk in visiting these sites. I know that there can be websites that download viruses to your computer when you visit them, etc., but are these websites with HTTPS errors any more dangerous in this regard or other regards as a website that uses HTTPS? Sometimes I see a website that I know is safe, but for some reason a specific link to a page within this website displays the error message, and sometimes it happens with websites I've never visited before.

Comment: Being able to observe network traffic is enough to highjack a user's session. So not only could someone see what you browse, they could also probe a website you've already visited for more information. They would have an especially rich source of information to explore if it's a social media website. No need, even, for someone to be eavesdropping the moment you sent your password. An old session could be taken over as long you didn't log out before bypassing warnings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some risks to HTTP sites even if you're not entering data.

There is the privacy risk, as others have pointed out. Someone in a position to observe your traffic can see a lot more about what you are doing. E.g. if you're browsing a news site over HTTPS, they can see that you're browsing the site; with HTTP they can tell what articles. There is a lot of additional metadata visible that could be used to fingerprint you; this can allow someone to correlate the activity they can observe with other sites and potentially identify you.

But the other big risk is the lack of integrity. With plain HTTP anyone your traffic is sent through can insert malicious files. E.g. your ISP or whoever's wireless you're using can insert ads, crypto miners or other malicious content. HTTPS provides integrity protection, so if working correctly, this means that an attacker would have to compromise the destination site to do this rather than just get you to connect to their WiFi.

Comment: Also, a MITM attacker could insert javascript and run code on your device.

Answer (score 3):

It is neither fully safe to visit a website with HTTPS since HTTPS only protects the communication between client and server and does not secure the web site itself or protects against deliberately serving malicious content. Nor is it fully unsafe to visit a site without HTTPS or with an invalid HTTPS certificate since even if there is a possibility of an attack an actual attack will not happen is most cases.  But there is of course an increased risk when no HTTPS is used or if HTTPS warnings need to be skipped in order to access the site since it adds additional ways for an attacker.

An error during validation of a certificate might point to an inability of the site admins or hosting provider to setup HTTPS in the correct way. This might actually be the consequence of a larger problem of not being able to properly secure the site or of not caring about this in the first place. Especially expired certificates highlight sites which are no longer maintained and where nobody actually cares about security. Such an abandoned HTTPS site is therefore likely more vulnerable to being attacked and to be used to serve malicious content than a well-managed plain HTTP site.

Errors about name mismatch instead are often the result of a larger hosting provider mixing customer domains with and without HTTPS certificates on the same IP address. This will usually result in the plain HTTP sites being accessible by HTTPS too, albeit with a non-matching certificate. Many search engines will unfortunately ignore certificate errors while crawling which results in these sites ending up in the search index with HTTPS and will immediately result in certificate errors when visiting from the search results. So getting such a warning when accessing a site from a search engine is still a serious problem but a less serious one than a long ago expired certificate or when getting a warning by following a link from somewhere outside a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the user does not enter their personal information, such information may still be sent from the browser (e.g. visiting a badly designed website, whose URL exposes your information).

Comment: Can you give an example what kind of personal information my browser may send without any input from me?

Comment: @MechMK1: there's been a lot of password auto-fill based attacks over the years, as well as fingerprinting tech.